# For the year 2010, I want to find the percent forest coverage of several sites with a radii of 10 km around each site

Tags: google-earth-engine

Currently this is my code for generating circles on a map in GEE:

```
//Define all coordinates
var pointList = [
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-82.964662, 8.78754421)),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-82.833405, 8.9453785)),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-83.521707, 8.694056)),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-83.33052, 8.697707)),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-83.203795, 8.702278)),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-83.662379, 8.685824)),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-84.376866, 9.818762)),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-83.485502, 8.714672)),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-83.672295, 8.691173)),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-83.588293, 8.694951)),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-83.258253, 8.656794)),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-83.06069, 8.603446)),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-83.19873, 8.67821)),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-82.993605, 8.785756)),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-83.666655, 8.689647)),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-82.976395, 8.806548)),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-83.600086, 8.697011)),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-83.519634, 8.562216)),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-83.316672, 8.746735)),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-83.518933, 8.702871)),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-83.270145, 9.769966)),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-83.72393, 9.16715))
];

var pointCollection = ee.FeatureCollection(pointList);

// Define a function of buffering to create circles around sites
var buffer_circles = function(feature) {
    var intermediate_buffer = feature.buffer(10000);  // buffer radius in meters
       return(intermediate_buffer); // Returns the circles
      };

// Apply function to map
var bounding_circles = pointCollection.map(buffer_circles);
    Map.centerObject(pointCollection); // Center map on sample points
    Map.addLayer(bounding_circles, {color: '#ff4c4c'}, "Buffering Circles");
```

I want to find the percent forest coverage of each circle for 2010. I've already looked through the GEE website, forums on this site and whatever popped up in my Googling sprees, and Youtube videos. This is my current code that I reverse-engineered using what I found for calculating forest coverage and I'm getting an error that says:

> Layer 2: Layer error: Image.projection, argument 'image': Invalid type.
>   Expected type: Image.
>   Actual type: ImageCollection.

Here is the code for that:

```
var cc = ee.Number(70)
var pixels = ee.Number(6)
var lossPixels = ee.Number(6)

//gfc2010 : global forest change in 2010
var gfc2010 = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection("GLCF/GLS_TCC"))

var canopyCover = gfc2010.select(['tree_canopy_cover'])

var canopyCover10 = canopyCover.gte(cc).selfMask();

var contArea = canopyCover10.connectedPixelCount();
var minArea = contArea.gte(pixels).selfMask();

var prj = gfc2010.projection();
var scale = prj.nominalScale();
Map.addLayer(minArea.reproject(prj.atScale(scale)), {
    palette: ['#899fed']
});

var forestArea = minArea.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).divide(10000);
var forestSize = forestArea.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: pointCollection.geometry(),
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e13
});
```

I am very new to GEE and coding in Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script has a few issues. The Error you are getting is because of this:

```
//gfc2010 : global forest change in 2010
var gfc2010 = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection("GLCF/GLS_TCC"))
```

It tries to cast an ImageCollection to an Image, which doesn't work. Here's how you would fix that:

```
//gfc2010 : global forest change in 2010
var gfc2010 = ee.ImageCollection("GLCF/GLS_TCC")
  .filterDate("2010-01-01")
  .filterBounds(pointCollection)
  .mosaic()
```

This filters to 2010, to your region of interest and then converts the ImageCollection to a single image with `.mosaic()`.

Another error in your script is here:

```
Map.addLayer(minArea.reproject(prj.atScale(scale)), {
    palette: ['#899fed']
});
```

This adds an Image to the Code Editor at a fixed scale. This is heavily discouraged because no matter your zoom level, it will always query the data at a predefined scale. This slows down the display immensly. Instead replace it with this:

```
Map.addLayer(minArea, {
    palette: ['#899fed']
});
```

Lastly, instead of `.reduceRegion()` you should use `.reduceRegions()` to get a value for every circle instead of only one value for all of them:

```
var forestSize = forestArea.reduceRegions({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    collection: pointCollection,
    scale: 30
});
```

I'm not sure the script now outputs exactly what you want but you can check that yourself and if you run into any other roadblocks you can't solve yourself, you can post a follow-up question.

Here's a link to the full script with the improvements:

[Earth Engine](https://code.earthengine.google.com/cd14984eb3f85471d4559d6299dc677c)

Comment: Thank you so much for responding and helping me, I really appreciate it! The code visually gives me what I want, but I had some questions about the output in the console. I clicked FeatureCollection, features, a number, and properties I get a value for sum and I was wondering is this the percentage of forest cover for that area or is it something else? I was also wondering if the output is valid because only 6 of the points returned a nonzero value for sum, whereas the map appears to have more than 6 points that have forest in them.

Comment: I'm thinking this might be a problem because several circles overlap so does the algorithm only count the parts of a circle that don't overlap with other circles?

Comment: No, overlapping circles shouldn't be an issue. What you are doing in the code is only counting forests which have a canopy cover of >70% and are connected to 6 other pixels with >70% canopy cover. This probably results in lower values than expected. Also, if the answer was helpful you can mark it as accepted to show that your reveived an answer.